# My kids are asking for Angry Birds Knock On Wood for the holidays, is it safe?

Tags: safety

This game doesn't seem very safe... throwing plastic birds around trying to knock things over? But the kids are incessantly asking for it.

Comment: This is an incredibly vague question. How old are your kids? How clumsy are they? How prone are they to hurting each other? Etc.

Comment: @DA01, this is more about the game than the kids I think.

Comment: But 'safe' is a relative term. I imagine this game is as safe as stacking up blocks and throwing a ball at them.

Answer (score 9):

It's actually not nearly as unsafe as it seems. For one thing the birds are soft rubber squeeze toys. I've been hit in the head with them and it barely stings. The catapult for launching them is pretty weak, at full pull you can fling them about 5' distance, and about 3' in the air.

To be honest, if your kids are asking for this game by name, they're likely already familiar with the concept of the game and are trying to implement it with their existing toys. I'd much rather sit down at the table with my family and this game than walk into my son's room and find him throwing stuffed animals across the room into piles of blocks or lego castles. (Been there, done that.) Now that he knows we have the game he asks to play it instead of staging it with his other toys.

Answer (score 4):

My 9-yr. old son just received two of these games the other day as early Christmas presents. Believe me, they are much safer than the Nerf darts normally whizzing through the air at our house.

Let kids be kids. Get them the game.

Answer (score -3):

Just because they want it doesn't mean they need it and doesn't mean you must get it for them. It sounds to me like you don't want to get it for them but you also don't want to disappoint them. This is a great time to teach them that want and need are two different things.  Teaching them that they don't always get what they want is a good lesson in growing up.  As well, it does seem dangerous, even if it doesn't hurt what are you teaching them about throwing things in the house, which can break things even if they don't hurt people.  As well, why do they need to be throwing things in the house?  Teaching them that there are rules and there are inappropriate items out there that they just can't have is an important lesson (as I stated above, but it deserves repeating).  Stay strong to what you think is the right thing to do, sound like not buying it, and remember that you are the parent and know what is best.

All in all I recommend not buying it and if they complain teach them that sometimes we don't get what we want.  That everything they need and most things they want they get, but sometimes the answer is no.

Comment: The focus of the question is on "is this toy safe". While I agree with the sentiment that "just because they want it doesn't mean they need it" wholeheartedly, I think you may be over-reading the OP's hesitation about buying it. As for teaching children about throwing things in the house, is that really any different from [this classic toy](http://www.amazon.com/Tic-Tac-Throw-Bean-Game/dp/B005QDB13G)?

Comment: The question is whether it's safe, not whether it's time to teach your kids that they can't always get what they want. Incidentally, Christmas is the *worst* time to **start** trying to teach this (admittedly important) lesson, as literally their entire world is singing the opposite song, and you end up looking like this guy: http://youtu.be/nzXKWKaxt3c

You need to build up to it over the year.